# Support for dark and light mode in ChartKick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, chart.js, chartkick

Chat JS seems to be offering dark and light mode support according to this GitHub PR:
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/8685

The question is, how to call colorMode: "auto" in ChartKick as ChartJS default is none...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mr got closed, so there is no `colorMode` option in chart.js. To achieve a dark/light mode you will need to adjust all of the colors yourself.

The main colors you want to adjust are `data.datasets[datasetIndex].backgroundColor` and `options.scales[scaleId].grid.color`. That will make most of your chart be visible on light and dark

Comment: crap!
I just need the labels in my case... so I will look at the options for this.